# ¿Cómo transferir contenido de un datagridview a reporte con reportviewer? C# windows form

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

Buen día, estoy trabajando en una tarea escolar, y tengo que pasar algunos datos de un formulario a un reporte en reportviewer, he logrado pasar los datos de algunos labels y textbox correctamente, pero al querer pasar los datos de mi datagridview, solo se muestra una de la filas en el reporte, concretamente la ultima fila, digamos que tengo 5 filas y solo se muestra la numero 5, mientras las 4 anteriores no se muestran. si alguien sabe alguna solución y pudiese explicarme se lo agradecería mucho.

**Estes es mi codigo de formulario principal**

```
TicketDeVenta tick = new TicketDeVenta();

  Datos dat = new Datos();
  dat.Expendio = "Local Principal";
  dat.Fecha = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
  dat.Cliente = "Publico en general";
  dat.IVA = "Incluido en el precio";
  dat.Total = TotalApagarOP2.Text;
  dat.Cambio = CambioDelEfectivoOP.Text;

  for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i ++)
  {
    dat.Cantidad = (double)Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    dat.Nombre = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
    dat.Marca = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
    dat.Precio = (string)(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

   }
    tick.Datos.Add(dat);
    tick.Show();
```

**Este es el código de mi clase Datos**

```
public class Datos
{
    public string Expendio { get; set;}
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Cliente { get; set; }
    public string IVA { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
    public string Cambio { get; set; }

    //del grid
    public double Cantidad { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Marca { get; set; }
    public string Precio { get; set; }
}
```

**El codigo de mi reporte**

```
 private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Datos));
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

    }
```

Comment: En tu reportViewer tenes el componente que carga una lista de datos? Y mirando tu codigo, le estas pasando un solo objeto, lo estas sobre escribiendo todo el tiempo en lugar de pasarle un `Array` o `List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero deberás separar tu clase, ya que como esta ahora siempre almacenas los últimos datos.

```
 public class Datos
    {
        public string Expendio { get; set;}
        public string Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        public string IVA { get; set; }
        public string Total { get; set; }
        public string Cambio { get; set; }
        public List<Info>info{get;set}//Creas una lista para almacenar los demas datos
    }
    public class Info//Creas una nueva clase
       {
            public double Cantidad { get; set; }
            public string Nombre { get; set; }
            public string Marca { get; set; }
            public string Precio { get; set; }
      }
```

Segundo en tu código principal deberás modificar a algo como esto para que la lista almacene los datos.

```
TicketDeVenta tick = new TicketDeVenta();

  Datos dat = new Datos();
  dat.Expendio = "Local Principal";
  dat.Fecha = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
  dat.Cliente = "Publico en general";
  dat.IVA = "Incluido en el precio";
  dat.Total = TotalApagarOP2.Text;
  dat.Cambio = CambioDelEfectivoOP.Text;
  dat.Info = new public List<Info>();//Creas una nueva instancia de la clase

  for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i ++)
  {
    Info info=new Info();//Creas una instancia
    info.Cantidad = (double)Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    info.Nombre = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
    info.Marca = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
    info.Precio = (string)(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    dat.Info.Add(info);//Almacenas en la lista que creamos.
   }
    tick.Datos.Add(dat);
    tick.Show();
```

Espero te sirva.-

Comment: Hola amigo, agradezco mucho tu respuesta, no fue precisamente la solución, pero me ayudo bastante. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No se que tipo de dato es `tick`, pero por lo que veo debes mover tu `tick.Datos.Add`, dentro de tu `for`

```
  for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i ++)
  {
    dat.Cantidad = (double)Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    dat.Nombre = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
    dat.Marca = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
    dat.Precio = (string)(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

    tick.Datos.Add(dat);
  }
    tick.Show();
```

Comment: Tampoco se que tipo de datos seria `tick` pero la logica del algoritmo presupone que  `tick.Datos.Add(dat);` debe estar dentro del lazo for, si no esta claro que solo se agregará el ultimo registro, esto son el tipo de problemas que no hace falta conocer ese tipo de datos, solo se requiere entender cual es la logica del lazo for, para darse cuenta que solo estas agregando un registro y que solo será el ultimo.

Comment: **tick** es la palabra reservada que uso al instanciar otro formulario que es donde agrege mi reporte rdlc su codigo es el siguiente, y disculpa por no haber aclarado eso en primer lugar.

Comment: public List<Datos> Datos = new List<Datos>(); 
        public TicketDeVenta()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TicketDeVenta_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }

        private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Datos));
         this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }

Comment: Te comento que intente clocando  **tick.Datos.Add(dat);** dentro del bucle, pero lo que sucedio es que me imprime los mismo 5 veces.

Comment: los primeros campos te debe imprimir los mismo, los campos cantidad, precio, marca y nombre deberia cambiar, a no ser que tu grid tenga esos mismos datos.

Comment: Eso no serviría ya que solo agregara la misma instancia. Lo que falta es que esos datos se almacenen en una lista.

Comment: @CL. los esta agregando en una lista, con el metodo Add. Siempre repetira los primeros campos y luego cambia las cantidades, nombre y precio.

Comment: @RamiroBarone si, pero estaría mal, ya que cuando modificas un dato de la instancia se cambiara para todo lo almacenado en esa lista, por ejemplo, si en dat.Cantidad comienza en 1 y agrega hasta el valor 5, en la lista existirán los 5, pero en dat.Cantidad que deberia aparecer 1,2,3,4,5 solo aparecera 5,5,5,5,5.-

Comment: Si, tenes razon se me habia pasado por alto.